# Binding TextBlock color to Button IsEnabled from Style

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to define a `Style` that could be used where `Button` holds a `TextBlock` as its `Content` and when `Button` has `IsEnabled`=False I want to set `TextBlock`'s `Foregroung` color.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource TransparentButtonStyle}" 
        IsEnabled="{Binding IsAllowed}">
      <TextBlock Text="Click Me" 
                 Style="{StaticResource HyperLinkStyle}">
      </TextBlock>
</Button>

<Style x:Key="TransparentButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
     <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                 <Border Background="Transparent">
                     <ContentPresenter/>
                 </Border>
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="HyperLinkStyle" TargetType="TextBlock"> 
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"  />
     <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
             <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightBlue" />
             <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
         </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Can I modify the `TextBlock`'s `Style` to grab the parent `Button`'s `IsEnabled` value somehow to be able to set the `Foreground` color ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just add `<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">` to your HyperLinkStyle, but I recommend you to create LinkButtonStyle instead, so you final markup fill be much cleaner:

```
  <Button Content="Link text"  Style="{StaticResource LinkButtonStyle}" />
```

this just makes your views much cleaner...

here's my LinkButton template:

```
<Style x:Key="LinkButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource LinkButtonText}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <TextBlock x:Name="ContentPresenter" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                           Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                           HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                           VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentPresenter" Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource LinkButtonDisabled}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentPresenter" Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get to `Button` you can use `DataTrigger` with `RalativeSource` binding

```
<Style.Triggers>
   <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <!-- Setters -->
   </Trigger>
   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="False">
      <!-- Setters -->
   </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

but if you want to make your `Style` independent of what is the parent then normal `Trigger` on `IsEnabled` property should work just as good

```
<Style.Triggers>
   <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <!-- Setters -->
   </Trigger>
   <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
      <!-- Setters -->
   </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

normal `Trigger` should work because `IsEnabled` value is influenced by [`UIElement.IsEnabledCore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isenabledcore(v=vs.110).aspx) which

> Gets a value that becomes the return value of IsEnabled in derived classes
>   ...
>   The default implementation of this property caches the value and also calculates whether the parent element of this element is enabled. (If the parent is not enabled, the child element cannot be effectively enabled in practical user interface (UI).)

so basically if parent `Button` is disabled child `TextBlock` will be disabled as well